# X5R capacitor derating and highpass filters

Tags: voltage, capacitor, high-pass-filter, derating

X5R capacitors derate to about roughly 85% when DC voltage is applied, from what I have been told.

Does this have an effect on high pass filters, even though HF filters off DC (0Hz)?
If I wanted to test voltage derating on capacitors and its effect on an AC signal, how would I do so?

edit:1

[image]

edit: 2

[image]

edit: 3

[image]

I tried with different frequency and tried adding a Voltage offset, and these were the results i got. When I simulated it didn't show any change. When i tried to run a test on a small HF circuit with a 100nF X5R capacitor and a 1k, the amplitude of my output reduced.
At higher frequencies the changes in amplitude were wayy smaller compared the frequencies at and under the cutoff frequency((1446Hz).

Comment: What is your peak voltage for any DC component and the HF ripple?

Comment: It's much cheaper to buy the cap that you need, rather than use a cap that's not and test it.

Comment: The X5R capacitor i'm currently using is 100nF capacitor with a voltage rating on 10V parallel with a 1.1kohm resistance. So it's cutoff freq is about 1446 Hz. When testing the output of a 1460 Hz sinewave with a 9.6Vpp, the result of the scope gave a slighty sine with lower amplitude.

Comment: Scott Seidman. I wanted to see the characteristics of the X5R capacitor and it's effect on a sine wave

Comment: What is the TOLERANCE of your cap?  If it's 20%, your capacitance can be anywhere between 80 and 120 nF.

Comment: @ScottSeidman The tolerance is 10%.
I have edited my post and placed a small schematics on voltage derating characteristics. I was if this would have any effect on the high pass filter

Comment: Cap parallel with resistor doesn't seem to be a high pass filter to me. Do you have a schematic?

Comment: I would never use a 10 V cap at 9.6 Vpp! What single digit cents are you trying to save?

Comment: @JasonHan. I might have described it wrong.
But this should be the schematic, i have added it as a second edit. If i wanted to apply a DC voltage to derate the capacitor, where would i apply it and would it have an effect on the AC signal i insert?

Comment: I see. According to the graph that you provided, the capacitance will shift according to the DC voltage that you applied. If you want to test the derating, build an inverting op amp amplifier. Connect the dc bias to the op amp + terminal.

Comment: @JasonHan Thanks i appreciate the suggestion, but i was wondering if i the voltage derating applies to capacitors in a high-pass filter. If i wanted to apply a DC voltage to derate the capacitor, and an AC signal, would my AC signal begin to flat out at its peaks?

Comment: It will not flat out, you'll still get a sine tone but with reduce amplitude with some distortion. Do take note changing the DC bias will likely running this cap above it's allowed spec.

Answer (score 2):

"Derate" doesn't necessarily mean that the capacitance value changes -- it just means that some of the specs change.  For example, if the voltage rating for a 0.1 microfarad cap is 40V, derating by 75% would mean that you should not use it past 30V.

So, if you planned to use your high pass filter constructed with the above capacitor at above  30V, and it's spending most of it's time at DC, or with a large DC offset,  then yes, it is "affecting" the functionality of the circuit.

Comment: Multilayer cap derating have to refer to manufacturer datasheet. As the applied DC voltage reaching the rated voltage of the cap, the higher the capacitance loss.